# WPF Blend animation button events

Tags: .net, wpf, events, touch, blend

I have animations:

- btnHome.MouseEnter
- btnHome.MouseLeave

On mouse enter/leave they are called correctly, but on touch MouseEnter fires and MouseLeave not.

Is there a way to have event for TouchLeave (there is no such event in Blend for button) so i can call this animation, or at least to prevent animations when touch used?

Comment: What do you mean by touch "MouseEnter"? That the mouse left button is clicked when you enter or leave the button?

Comment: You can always try:
Make new project, put one button, in Blend make 2 events: MouseEnter, MouseLeave, set for first event to change text to red, second to get it back to black.

With your mouse, when you go over/out of that button, it will change color to red and back, but with Touch screen, when you touch button, it will go in red, and never go black again.